# When convergence a.s. implies convergence in mean?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Can someone help me with proving the following:

> Assume that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$, where $X_n$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables. Furthermore, assume that the sequence $\Bbb E[X_n]$ converges to $\Bbb E[X]< \infty$. Now, prove that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L_1$, i.e., that $\Bbb E|X_n-X| \to 0$ as $n$ grows.

Thank you!

Comment: A hint to get you started: $E[|X_n-X|]=E[(X_n-X)_+]+E[(X_n-X)_-]$ while $E[X_n-X]=E[(X_n-X)_+]-E[(X_n-X)_-]$. Since $E[X_n-X] \to 0$, you can add or subtract these equations to each other to essentially remove the positive or negative part from the problem (at your discretion). Another hint: don't forget to use the nonnegativity, the result is very much false otherwise. For example, if $Y$ is a fixed U(0,1) variable then $X_n=\begin{cases} -n & 0 \leq Y<1/n \\ 0 & 1/n \leq Y<1-1/n \\ n & 1-1/n \leq Y \leq 1 \end{cases}$ fails to converge in mean to $0$.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy! Because I must have a complete proof as soon as possible, I have to ask for a few more hints... Let us assume that we add these equations, such that we remove the negative part from the problem. How do I continue? What are the main tools and theorems? Thank you in advance for your help!